# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context. xcode swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, debugging

I am in the process of building a flashcard app. I have attached my code below. When the code below runs the user should be able to swipe left and right through an array of Cards(each card contains an image coupled with a sound. There are two arrays of Cards called firstList and secondList). When an image is tapped, the sound it is coupled with should play. I am not getting an issue playing the sound or swiping through a single list. However, I am getting an error when I try to combine and swipe through "firstList" and "secondList". One of the errors I cannot seem to figure out is "type of expression is ambiguous without more context".  please see the code and the error below

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  {



var imageIndex: Int = 0
@IBAction func home(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

struct List {
    let words: [Card] /*Create array of cards*/
    var active: Bool
}




let firstList = [
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lake")!, soundUrl: "Lake"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lamb")!, soundUrl: "Lamb"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lamp")!, soundUrl: "Lamp"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lark")!, soundUrl: "Lark"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "leaf")!, soundUrl: "Leaf"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "leash")!, soundUrl: "Leash"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "left")!, soundUrl: "Left"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "leg")!, soundUrl: "Leg"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lime")!, soundUrl: "Lime"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lion")!, soundUrl: "Lion"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lips")!, soundUrl: "Lips"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "list")!, soundUrl: "List"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lock")!, soundUrl: "Lock"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "log")!, soundUrl: "Log"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "look")!, soundUrl: "Look"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "love")!, soundUrl: "Love"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lunch")!, soundUrl: "Lunch")
        ]

let secondList = [
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lake")!, soundUrl: "Lake"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lamb")!, soundUrl: "Lamb"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lamp")!, soundUrl: "Lamp"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lark")!, soundUrl: "Lark"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "leaf")!, soundUrl: "Leaf"),

    ]




    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let list1 = List(words:firstList, active: true)
        let list2 = List(words:secondList, active: true)

        var imageList: [String]{
            let wordLists = [list1, list2]

            print((wordLists[0] ).words[0].soundurl)


            let active = wordLists.reduce([]) { (result:[String], list:List) in
                if list.active {
                    return result + list.words

                } else {
                    return result
                }
            }

            return active

        }


    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    imgPhoto.image = (imageList[0] ).image

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    leftSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    rightSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right


    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

}

@IBAction func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("hhh")
    imageList[imageIndex].playSound()
    // Your action
}

func Swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :
            print("User swiped right")

            // decrease index first

            imageIndex -= 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex < 0 {

                imageIndex = words.count - 1

            }

            imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            print("User swiped Left")
            // increase index first

            imageIndex += 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex > itemList.count - 1 {

                imageIndex = 0

            }



            imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image
        default:


            break //stops the code/codes nothing.
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]

```
import Foundation; import UIKit; import AVFoundation

var player: AVAudioPlayer?

class Card: NSObject
{
var image: UIImage
var soundUrl: String


init(image: UIImage, soundUrl: String) {
    self.image = image
    self.soundUrl = soundUrl
}
 func playSound()

{ print("play")
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a") else { return }
    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    print("hhh")
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` is of type `[String]`, but `list.words` is of type `[Card]`. Swift doesn't know how you want to combine those two in the statement `return result + list.words`.

Swift requires you to be very specific about types. So, you need to specify exactly what you want when there is any question.

You don't show your `Card` type, so I'll give you a general example:

```
var list1:[String] = ["a", "b", "c"]
var list2:[Any] = ["d", "e", "f"]

let newList = list1 + list2
// error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

This combination should be possible, as both lists contain `String` values. However, since `list2` declares it is of type `[Any]`, Swift isn't sure of the intent for the concatenation. It'll give you the "ambiguous" error.

To fix this, you must be specific as to the types in question - meaning you must cast as applicable to the types you want Swift to use:

```
let newList = list1 + (list2 as! [String])
```

Since `list1` is already of `[String]` type, Swift now knows you want a resulting `[String]` type. (Swift will implicitly assign `[String]` as the type for `newList` in this case.)

Also note that your types must be compatible to do this! If `[Card]` is not something that will convert to `[String]` you'll get another error.

Comment: ive added my card class if you could take a look.

Comment: Your `Card` class is definitely not compatible with `String`, @AnthonyRubin.   You might approach an instructor or mentor for assistance. If none are handy, you can purchase time with a mentor on a site such as [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io)